# Create SQL table from parquet files

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, apache-spark, parquet

I am using R to handle large datasets (largest dataframe 30.000.000 x 120). These are stored in Azure Datalake Storage as parquet files, and we would need to query these daily and restore these in a local SQL database. Parquet files can be read without loading the data into memory, which is handy. However, creating SQL tables from parquuet files is more challenging as I'd prefer not to load the data into memory.

Here is the code I used. Unfortunately, this is not a perfect reprex as the SQL database need to exist for this to work.

```
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)
library(sparklyr)
library(DBI)

# Create test data
test <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))

# Save as parquet file
write_parquet(test2, tempfile(fileext = ".parquet"))


# Load main table
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = spark_home_dir())
test <- spark_read_parquet(sc, name = "test_main", path = "/tmp/RtmpeJBgyB/file2b5f4764e153.parquet", memory = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)

# Save into SQL table
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = connection,
                  name = DBI::Id(schema = "schema", table = "table"), 
                  value = test)
```

Is it possible to write a SQL table without loading parquet files into memory?

Answer (score 4):

I lack the experience with `T-sql` bulk import and export but this is likely where you'll find your answer.

```
library(arrow)
library(DBI)
test <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
f <- tempfile(fileext = '.parquet')
write_parquet(test2, f)

#Upload table using bulk insert
dbExecute(connection, 
  paste("
    BULK INSERT [database].[schema].[table]
    FROM '", gsub('\\\\', '/', f), "' FORMAT = 'PARQUET';
  ")
)
```

here I use `T-sql`'s own [`bulk insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command.
***Disclaimer*** I have not yet used this command in `T-sql`, so it may riddled with error. For example I can't see a place to specify snappy compression within the documentation, although it can be specified if one instead defined a custom file format with [`CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Now the above only inserts into an existing table. For your specific case, where you'd like to create a new table from the file, you would likely be looking more for [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) using [`CREATE TABLE AS [select statement]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
column_definition <- paste(names(column_defs), column_defs, collapse = ',')
dbExecute(connection, 
paste0("CREATE TABLE MySqlTable
AS 
SELECT *
FROM 
  OPENROWSET(
    BULK '", f, "' FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
  ) WITH (
    ", paste0([Column definitions], ..., collapse = ', '), "
  );
")
```

where `column_defs` would be a **named** list or vector describing giving the SQL data-type definition for each column. A (more or less) complete translation from R data types to is available on the [T-sql documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/r/r-libraries-and-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15) (Note two very necessary translations: `Date` and `POSIXlt` are not present). Once again disclaimer: My time in T-sql did not get to BULK INSERT or similar.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver for the contribution!

From these alternatives, BULK INSERT seems more straightforward. Could you have any idea hot the CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT should be used to make BULK INSERT to work?

Comment: I'm glad i could give you a place to start at, at the very least. I lack the experience with the specific function (as the IT decided snowflake was better on our end). But simply using `FORMAT = 'PARQUET'` might work. Alternatively example `D` in the link (if you click the query in my answer) has an example with the format. After this it might be as simple as just using `FORMAT = [name of the format you made]`. If it doesn't work i think the next best option is the second one.

Comment: Thanks again, that was helpful! It seems that neither option is currently optimal as I have SQL server v12 which does not support creating external file formats.

Comment: After an hour of testing on a newly created local database, it also seems that bulk uploading is restricted to their Azure version. Sql server indeed always has restrictions depending on version and plan. Your simplest solution then might be to partition the parquet file and upload each partition from memory and simply accept that this will take time.

Comment: I was afraid that it has to be done like you described. I really appreciate the effort!

I'll leave the ticket open in case somebody finds another working solution later.