# How to have consistent datatype while exporting a pandas dataframe?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have been working with huge datasets since a few weeks and wanted to improve the efficiency.
I recently came across https://pythonspeed.com/. Amazing website which has many suggestions to improve the efficiency.

I came across few useful suggestions to change my datatype. Pandas by default saves int64, float64. I realised I don't require int64 and int32 is sufficient for me. Another suggestion of replacing unique strings with category has help me to compress my data a lot.
Just to show some numbers a sample dataframe was around 4.6gb after changing a few datatype I was able to reduce the dataframe size to 2.4-2.5gb roughly saved 40% space.

I have attaced a sample image below:

[image]

code:

```
data_type_dict = {'low' :'float32', 'close' :'float32', 'high' :'float32','open':'float32','volume':'int32','ticker_name':'category'}
 
data = data.astype(data_type_dict)
```

I tried exporting the compressed dataframe to csv and sql server using pandas' to_csv and to_sql respectively but the size of the data was same as the original.

Comment: Have you tried parquet? `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html`

Comment: If I'm not wrong praquet creates a gzip file right? The goal is not to create a gzip file but to push the data with the same specifications to sql server or to use it as a csv.

Comment: No it's not. please search it will be interesting.

Comment: Hey, mate it kinda worked. I could save a parquet file with the specs I wanted. Now I need to find a way to transfer it into sql server as I have been using it as my main database. I'm reading the Apache Arrow documentation. Is there anything specific that I can read/ refer to?

Comment: arrow is sufficient. this post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935557/create-sql-table-from-parquet-files

Comment: The attached link is for R and not python

Comment: in pandas you can read parquet file as dataframe. From there you can simply use sql connector to upload sql.

Comment: Exactly but in the end the sql connector ( say pandas .to_sql) will use Pandas' default values (int64, float64, string etc)

Comment: Parquet is a file format, it stores data in columnar format. I haven't tried this on sql.